# No puedo conectarme a TFS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Instalé TFS 2017 en un server de la empresa. Desde dentro del server puedo acceder normalmente a `https://server-name/tfs`. 
Pero cuando lo hago desde mi maquina local no me deja.

Desde IE:

> Error DNS temporal. Intenta actualizar la página.Código de error: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND)

Y desde el VS

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server

Alguna idea? Será que no tengo acceso remoto al server o sera algo del TFS?

Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que pases por [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En este caso, es muy complicado ayudarte ya que no conocemos la configuración del servidor ni de la red local de tu empresa. Sin esos datos, solo podríamos adivinar, aunque obviamente el problema es que desde fuera del servidor no existe acceso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema:

> Estás fuera de la red

Para solucionarlo:

1. La configuración de DNS de tu computadora apunte el DNS del server de la empresa. Ésto puedes hacerlo de 2 maneras: editando el archivo hosts ubicado en C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ o mediante la asignación de la IP del DNS en configuraciones de redes.
2. Con ello ahora sí, estás en la misma red de la empresa.
3. En caso estés fuera del dominio, necesitas un usuario que sea tuyo. Y si estás en el dominio, tu usuario y contraseña del directorio activo será tu credencial para acceder al TFS.
4. Happy coding :D

Comment: Gracias! Hice eso. Y aparte me habilitaron el acceso al server desde los puertos 80 y 443, se ve que los tenían bloqueados. No entiendo mucho de redes pero algo así. Saludos!!

Comment: ¡Que felicidad hermano¡ ¡Dale con todo el power 2.0! y que sigan los éxitos con el desarrollo :D